# Adjusting Height of Segment Control in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I would like to know if there's any way to change the height of a Segment Control, or perhaps changing the font size of the control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this only from code, not in InterfaceBuilder. IB tries to stay within [Apple's HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ApplicationControls/ApplicationControls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW11), that's why it does not allow to change the height.

If you change the height (frame) programmatically, you also have to change the image using setImage:forSegmentAtIndex: since the default image looks terrible when streched.

Comment: well.. seems i have to do it in a hard way =)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old one, and already answered, but for other searching;

I found that changing the style to BAR in the attributes in IB is a very fast and acceptable workaround, which uses a much shorter graphic.

Comment: Really nice, I didn't see this option :)

Answer (score 1):

When I tried it I couldn't assign the height directly.  I had to do this:

```
- (void)adjustSegControlHeight:(UISegmentedControl*)segControl :(NSInteger)newHeight {

        CGRect segControlFrame = segControl.frame;
        segControlFrame.size.height = newHeight;
        segControl.frame = segControlFrame;
}
```

But I decided to use BAR method anyhow.

Comment: BTW: [segControl frame].size.height = newHeight  will not work because [segControl frame].size.height is readonly property.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but if someone out there is still trying to figure it out, this is the way I used to do it. Hope it would be helpful for someone in need.

`UISegmentedControl *customeSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 206.0f, 7.0f , 110.0f, 30.0f)];`

Answer (score 1):

**Fortunately you can change the height from the xib as well.**

You can do so through the `xib` as well. Just add a segment control into the `xib`. Then open the `xib` in TextEdit. There you will find the code

```
<segmentedControl opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="top" segmentControlStyle="plain" selectedSegmentIndex="0" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="B99-Tt-vJG">

<rect key="frame" x="222" y="82" width="123" height="44"/>
```

Here you change the height from 44 to any required height. You can change the height of any `UIConponent` like this. Even for the `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in interface builder these days in case someone stumbles on this question.

1: click the segmented control in IB
2: on the grid view find the "pin" control in the bottom right.
3: click "pin height" 
4: open up the size inspector in the utilities area (now you will have a height constraint)
5: click the gear and choose "Select and edit"

Pretty hack-y but if you can't get this to update via code this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in iOS 7+ using AutoLayout is just add a height constraint to the segmented control and then update frames to resolve the auto layout issues. IB will then show the layout at the desired height. One can then edit the height constraint to change the height at any time from IB.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfect for me. And it's updated for new iOS and Xcode versions.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yoursegmentedControl
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:THE NEW HEIGHT];
[yoursegmentedControl addConstraint:constraint];
```